# how can I export maobox 3D map model as single prefab in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want a real-world campus 3d map model for an AR project, and I utilize mapbox sdk to generate the campus. But some buildings is not needed for me in this map, when I delete them, after I click "Play", all the changes will disappear. Therefore, I cannot add interaction on all buildings, since it will initialize anyway :( Is there any other tools can help me create simple 3D object, rather than a online map?

(Unity 2021)
I use unity 2021, rather than 2018, since I need the AR foudation api

[image: Unity window]